# is it possible to pass data in fetch options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors, fetch

I have a react client-side app.

I want to wrap it with `express` so I won't have `CORS` issues when I'm fetching data from API's.

right now all my `fetch`es happens on the client-side with a some endpoints urls.

correct me please if I'm wrong.
In order to re-write correctly my fetch requests, I fetch from a route endpoint which I'll define in my `server.js` right ?

and in my `server.js` I'll make the actual `fetch` from the API, right ?

If so, then I have another question:

in my client-side I have some logics will determine how the `fetch's url` will be.

**My Question:** is there's a way for me to pass the correct url as some kind of a data into my fetch request, so I could use it in my server-side to make the actual API fetching?

here is an example of my code and what i try to understand if possible:

```
const { current, amount, page} = this.pagination;
const { client_id, search } = this.API;

const limit = `_limit=${amount}`;
let currentPage;
let url;

if(this.isFetching) return;

if(direction == 'next'){
   this.pagination.current = current + amount;
   currentPage = page + 1
   let offset = `_offset=${this.pagination.current}`;        
} else {
if(page !== 1) {
    this.pagination.current = current - amount;
    currentPage = page - 1
    let offset = `_offset=${this.pagination.current}`;           
} 

url = `${search}${client_id}&${limit}&${offset}`;   //  Here is the final url

fetch('/api', {data: url})   //  PSUEDO use of fetch, is it possible?
    .then(response => response.json())       
         .then(data => {
             this.fetchedProperties = [...data.search_results];
             this.pagination.page = currentPage; 
             this.isFetching = false;                                  
         });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The normal way to pass data from a client to an HTTP endpoint is to encode it in a query string.

```
http://example.com/fetch?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.net%2Ffoo%2Fbar%3Fquery%3Dsomething%26etc%3Detc
```